# Disable printing on ChromeOS

Tags: printing, administration, chrome-book

I have a couple of netbooks running ChromeOS for which I'd like to disable printing entirely. Preferably just for specific accounts (my kids), but if necessary, for the entire device.

I haven't found any settings available for this through the regular ChromeOS "settings" page - any ideas on how I can do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Visit the CUPS Admin page at http://localhost:631/admin

Add a new print queue with a null printer. Use `NOPRINT` for the queue name, or pick your own.

Make this queue the System Default Printer.

Stop the queue.

Tell your users "don't print".

Comment: Thank you! Will they be able to find printers over the network and print anyway? Telling my kids "don't print" has not worked thus far...